# restore -A usage

Tags: linux, restore, archive, dump

I have created a number of dump files using Linux dump(8), using the -A option to get a table of contents on disk (the backups are on tape). Now I'm trying to look into these archive files, using

```
 restore -i -A <archive>`
```

However, this insists on asking what tape to use, and complains if I say `none`. What am I doing incorrectly? I was hoping that I can use these archive index files without having to insert the tape to use.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the TOC files have been corrupted, and restore opens the tape when it gets to the end of this file.